# My C# form flickers and I can't fix it. I've tried everything

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, gdi+, flicker

I've been working on this program for about a month now, trying everything.  My program flickers no matter what I do, even on other machines.  It's just a background, an image, and a rectangle. Nothing huge or expensive.  Yet it still flickers.  I've tried setting DoubleBuffered to true, I've tried the override CreateParams (it makes my window black), I've tried reflection using a method, I've tried SetStyle to set DoubleBuffer, OptimizedDoubleBuffer,  UserPaint, AllPaintingInWmPain, and Opaque and none of them did anything when set to true.  I've scoured google and stackoverflow for an answer and none of them work.  I can't understand what I'm doing wrong.  I've added a zip of the code, exe, compiling script, and image.  What happens on my and others' computers is what is on the gif. The program is updating 4 times a second, more than enough time to draw a background, image, and square, yet it still flickers.  Please I need help.

Main.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class main{

    public static void Main(string[] args){
    
        Console.WriteLine("START");
    
        Engine.Init();
    
        while(true){
        
            Engine.MainDraw();
            Application.DoEvents();
        
            Thread.Sleep(250);
        }
    
        Console.WriteLine("END");
    
    }

}
```

Engine.cs:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

public class Engine : Form{
    
    public static Engine EngineForm = new Engine();
    public static Graphics g;
    
    /*
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams{
        get{
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x02000000;
            return cp;
        }
    }
    //*/
    
    /*
    public static void enableDoubleBuff(System.Windows.Forms.Control cont){
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo DemoProp = typeof(System.Windows.Forms.Control).GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance);
        DemoProp.SetValue(cont, true, null);
    }
    //*/
    
    public Engine(){
        
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        
        //enableDoubleBuff(this);
        
        this.SetStyle(
            ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer |
            ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer |
            ControlStyles.UserPaint |
            ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
            ControlStyles.Opaque
            ,
        true);
        this.UpdateStyles();
    }
    
    public static void Init(){
        EngineForm.Enabled = true;
        EngineForm.Visible = true;
        
        EngineForm.Activate();
        
        g = EngineForm.CreateGraphics();
    }
    
    public static Pen pen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0, 0), 5);
    
    public static Image image = Image.FromFile("bulbasaur.png");
    
    public static Color color = Color.FromArgb(200, 200, 255, 255);
    
    public static void MainDraw(){
        g.Clear(color);
        
        g.DrawImage(image, new PointF(0, 0));
        
        g.DrawRectangle(pen, 100, 100, 100, 100);
    }
    
}
```

What the program looks like:

[image: Program output.]

Comment: What does it look like when you omit that `g.Clear(color);` ?

Comment: This: `g = EngineForm.CreateGraphics();` is probably the worst thing you can do. The rest is in `Main`. Run your Form as usual, override its `OnPaint()` method, draw your stuff there, using the Graphics object that PaintEventArgs provides (if you want double buffering to work) -- No loops, this is not a Console app (and your code treats it like one). -- Set just `ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer` OR `DoubleBuffered = true` . Why `ControlStyles.Opaque`? What are you trying to do with this? Why the attempt to a singleton? Still Console stuff lurking in?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem you're seeing is because `CreateGraphics` creates a `Graphics` instance that bypasses the double buffering, giving you direct access to the window's canvas. Whatever you do with that `Graphics` object happens immediately on the screen.

To fix this you need to override one of the form methods that are invoked during the normal update process: `OnPaint` or `OnPaintBackground`. These receive a `Graphics` object that will work how you want it to, including handing double buffering:

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaintBackground(e);
    var g = e.Graphics;
    g.Clear(color);
    g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
    g.DrawRectangle(pen, 100, 100, 100, 100);
}
```

This is called whenever the form is being redrawn, before the controls are drawn, etc. You can make the form redraw by calling `Invalidate()`:

```
public static void MainDraw()
{
    EngineForm.Invalidate();
}
```

This posts a message to the window telling it to redraw. The next pass through your event loop that message will be processed and `OnPaintBackground()` is called.

The result is a smooth, flicker-free update. You can do animations and stuff without the `Clear` causing the background flashing and so on.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH.  I didn't know the graphics would be like that.   It worked. thank you SO MUCH ive spent so much time on this and it never worked thank you thank you thank you